# Advanced Ping Script

Tags: command-line, grep, text, ping

I want to have a little script which do a ping to 8.8.8.8 every 2 seconds and put only out the time. It should also put a "#" between every time. Like this:

```
25.5
#
25.4
#
and so on...
```

Finally i want to  have the output in a textfile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ping -i2 8.8.8.8 | awk -W interactive -F'[ =]' '{print $10"\n#"}' > output.text
```

Comment: @Colin Do you want the output *only* in the textfile, or also display it in the terminal?

Comment: only in the textfile.

Comment: @Florian Diesch my outputfile is emty when I run this line.

Comment: Test ist again, you need `-W interactive` to avoid buffering, but be in mind, the switch isn't POSIX compatible.